# Is there a way to insert into temporary table or a table from Execute statement

Tags: sql

I have a execute command that returns table `exec(@query)`. in sql

The above statement returns a table with below values

```
ColumnX  ColumnY
  A        5
  B        6
```

Now can we insert this execute statement into a temporary table similar like below.

```
Select * into ##temp from @query
```

However above query is throwing an error.

Please help

Comment: As far as I know, there is only one # in temp tables.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  As per the SQL tag info, just specifying SQL doesn't help much as there's several and your question doesn't include much information

Comment: @KadirÇolak- in SQL Server, double `#` indicates a global temporary table. But I'd not recommend anyone try using them.

Comment: The above query isn't valid ANSI/ISO SQL, and will result in syntax error on most dbms:s. Add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(ColumnX CHAR,  ColumnY INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP
EXEC(@query)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP (and the rest of us) know which dbms this is for.